# scp sometimes adds a '-f' flag to my command

Tags: command-line, ssh, scp

When using SCP to copy from a remote host to local (eg: `scp -v foo-host:/source/path dest` ) I look at the verbose output and notice this is the command sent over SSH:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /source/path
```

I can't think of any reason SSH would inject this flag, nor is it found in my manpage of my OS X (so this is a BSD command, and still part of OpenSSH). I can't seem to find any documentation on this anywhere. I don't have any alias set up to do this.

Why is this flag added, what adds it, and what is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /source/path
```

This is the command which your local `scp` process is requesting to be executed on the remote server. Scp works by launching another copy of scp on the remote host. The two scp instances communicate with each other to perform the file transfer--one sends files, and the other receives them.

"-f" is the flag which tells `scp` that it is running as a remote instance, and that it should send the file listed on the command line. Alternately, "-t" tells it that it's a remote instance which should receive files.

The flags aren't documented because they're not intended to be used by users. [Here is a page describing the scp protocol](https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works), if you're interested.